# PayPal API how to set custom billing frequency?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

How to set custom billing frequency to "QUARTERLY" during creating a billing plan?

Answer (score 0):

With the subscriptions API, when [creating a plan](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create):

```
      "frequency": {
        "interval_unit": "MONTH",
        "interval_count": 3
      },
```